# Random Teams based on Positions in Sports

Tags: randomized-algorithms, randomized

I have tried to find an answer to this but haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.

I am trying to develop a way in which I can have a random team selected based on skill set (1-5 with 5 being the strongest skilled player) as well as by position (Forward of Defense) so that the algorithm can organize the players based on skills  and position.

I know I can easily do one to randomly assign based on one criteria, but whats the best way to add the second criteria at the same time?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give more details?

Comment: Yes. I have two hockey teams. Each team has players rated from 1-5 with 5 being the best players. It is easy to randomly but equally split the teams based on the strength of the players (each team gets two Five rated platers, two four rated players, etc). But I also need to have them divided by position. Each team has four defense.

Comment: What is the input, and what is the required output?

Comment: I can give you random data if you'd like. Would that work or do you need the actual data?

Comment: Actual data is not necessary but a clear problem statement. My guess is your input is a set of players, where each player has a position and a skill level. The desired output is a bipartition of the players such that both teams are nearly equally strong on every position and overall, i.e. the difference of the sum of skill points on each position is minimal. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: The is pretty accurate although I don't know if the sum is the best way to determine whether a team is even. It would be best to try to equally distribute the best skills and worst skills on each team. Here is a sample data sheet with input and output. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u6orSshslvkp8mPZFdhWdyvE_roovLItioYol-xLXdk/edit?usp=sharing